# Azure SQL Intelligent Insights vs SQL Insights

Tags: sql-server, azure

Is there a difference between SQL Intelligent Insights and SQL insights?

https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/03/sql-insights-azure-preview/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/sql-insights-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/intelligent-insights-overview

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @Daisy, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Intelligent Insights only support Azure SQL database and Azure SQL Managed Instance. SQL insights support more versions include Azure SQL database and Azure SQL Managed Instance.

Like the description said of SQL insights is more comprehensive than SQL Intelligent Insights. SQL Intelligent Insights more focus on Azure database performance.